# A timer that measures length of mouse click

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I put this together using examples I could find from vanilla js, because I couldn't find exactly what I needed that was already done in p5.

It's doing what I want it to do which is give me a time between mousePressed and mouseReleased.

Question: is my method efficient? Looking for some expert advice after reading other comments about timers...don't want a timer running in the background because I haven't handled it correctly...

```
let timeTaken = 0;
let result = 0;
let timer;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500,500);
}

function draw() {
  background('black');
  fill('white');
  textSize(15);  
  text("timeTaken: "+timeTaken,20,20);
  textSize(60);
  text(result,100,100);
}

function mousePressed() {
  result = 0;
  timeTaken = 0;
  if (timer) {
      clearInterval(timer);
  }
  timer = setInterval(()=>{timeTaken++;}, 1);  
}

function mouseReleased() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  result = timeTaken;
}
```

Comment: Your question might be better recieved at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This might be more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since your code is actually working

Comment: @DTul - It really isn't. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder then he should rephrase the question as he states: "It's doing what I want it to do which is give me a time between mousePressed and mouseReleased."

Comment: @DTul - Well, he/she seems to *think* it works. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no need to mock. Define "works"...? my post humbly states that it "does what I want".  Clearly I am asking whether what I am doing is the right way to do it.

Comment: @matski - I wasn't mocking. I've also had code I *thought* worked that actually didn't, I just hadn't tested the conditions under which it didn't work. I should have thought from my answer that it was clear I was trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want a timer at all, not least because there's no guarantee that a timer will get fired when you asked for it to be fired. So if you start a timer with a 1ms interval, it might be called only two or three times in the course of 10 milliseconds, and so you end up with a count of 2 or 3 instead of 10. (In fact, timers are [clamped](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps), if you schedule a 1ms callback, after five callbacks the browser is supposed to throttle it and make it wait at least 4ms.¹)

Just record the current time on mousedown, and subtract it from the current time on mouseup, and that tells you how long it was down (in milliseconds):

```
let down;
let timeTaken = 0;

function mousePressed() {
  down = Date.now();
}

function mouseReleased() {
  timeTaken = Date.now() - down;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
let down;
let timeTaken = 0;

function mousePressed() {
  down = Date.now();
}

function mouseReleased() {
  timeTaken = Date.now() - down;
}

const target = document.getElementById("target");
target.addEventListener("mousedown", mousePressed);
target.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  mouseReleased();
  console.log(`Time taken: ${timeTaken}ms`);
});
```

```css
#target {
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">Click me<div>
```

---

¹ About clamping, you can see it in action here:

```js
const now = typeof performance !== "undefined" && performance.now ? performance.now.bind(performance) : Date.now.bind(Date);
let last = now();
let counter = 0;
const entries = [];
const timer = setInterval(() => {
    const n = now();
    entries.push(n - last);
    last = n;
    if (++counter > 15) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        for (const entry of entries) {
            console.log(entry + "ms");
        }
    }
}, 1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Exactly the expert advice I was looking for :)